# Smoother gradient transitions with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, opentk

I'm using the following shader to render a skydome to simulate a night sky. My issue is the clearly visible transitions between colours.

What causes these harsh gradient transitions?

[image]

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330
in vec3 worldPosition;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 outputColor;

void main()
{
    float height = 0.007*(abs(worldPosition.y)-200);    
    vec4 apexColor = vec4(0,0,0,1);
    vec4 centerColor = vec4(0.159, 0.132, 0.1, 1);

    outputColor = mix(centerColor, apexColor, height);
}
```

Fbo pixel format:

```
GL.TexImage2D(
    TextureTarget.Texture2D,
    0,
    PixelInternalFormat.Rgb32f,
    WindowWidth,
    WindowHeight,
    0,
    PixelFormat.Rgb,
    PixelType.Float,
    IntPtr.Zero )
```

Comment: How does the `RGB32F` format relate to all that? I'd say you don't see the banding in that texture, you just see it when you finally render (or blit) it to the final framebuffer, which typically just has 8 bits of precision.

Comment: @derhass I included the pixel format information incase it was related to the problem, seemed plausible given what I knew at the time.

Answer (score 8):

As Ripi2 explained, 24 bit color is unable to perfectly represent a gradient and  discontinuities between representable colours become jarringly visible on gradients of a single color.

To hide the color banding I implemented a simple form of ordered dithering with an 8x8 texture generated using this [bayer matrix algorithm](https://github.com/tromero/BayerMatrix).

[image]

```
vec4 dither = vec4(texture2D(MyTexture0, gl_FragCoord.xy / 8.0).r / 32.0 - (1.0 / 128.0));
colourOut += dither;
```

[image]

Comment: It wil be much more better if you edit borh question and answer and use some image which is not near black, which is perhaps the most difficult to see glitches.

Answer (score 2):

Normally monitors have 8 bits per channel of resolution. For example, the red intensity varies from 0 to 255.

If your window horizontal size is 768 pixels and you want a full gradient on red channel, then each color step takes 768/256 = 3 pixels. Depending on your eye health you may see bands.

How to do smooth gradient on those 3 pixels? Use [sub-pixel](https://www.grc.com/cleartype.htm) rendering.

Basically you "expand" the color step among the neighbour pixels: Add small amounts of other channels to neighbours, and reduce a bit the central pixel amount.

Comment: Sub-pixel rendering is for anti-aliasing. I think you mean [dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither).

Comment: @derhass Well, [Floyd–Steinberg dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering) would be used here. The point is using neighboring pixels to smooth the gradient.

Comment: Floyd-steinberg is hard to implement in a parallel fashio. simple ordered dithering (bayer) works very well on GPUs, and is easy to implement.